# lstlisting numbers ignores sideline

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

I am writing a paper with **ieeeconf** style. Now I added an lstlisting but the numbering is slighty off the normal text-region. You can see it here:

[image]

Can someone help me to fix this?

Code: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mmrrzpdrzdss

Comment: Please add minimal code directly to the question instead of (or in addition to) posting a link to Overleaf. By "slightly off", are you referring to the fact that the line number is placed in the margin?

Comment: If what you want to do is move the numbers into the column, add `xleftmargin=2em`  (modifying the length to something suitable), cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135705/listing-numbers-go-outside-margin

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That is exactly what I needed. Please write an answer, so I can accept it.